# Not possible to get notifications?

Tags: support

Seems that this site does not offer notifications when there is a new answer to your question or a topic that one is following. Is that really so?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't "follow" a topic, can you? Is there a UI element which lets you do that?

---

But you will get a notification:

- When someone *answers* a question you posted
- When someone *comments*, underneath anything (question or answer) that you posted
- When someone *edits* anything (question or answer) that you posted
- When someone *replies* to a previous comment you made, by including `@OPL` in their comment

---

Notifications appear in the toolbar at the top of the page, *when you next visit any page of the network*:

[image]

That notification icon ("inbox") becomes highlighted (i.e. a different color), and if you click on it you see a list of all recent notifications.

---

I think you can see a history of all notifications (from all sites) [here](https://stackexchange.com/users/11052751/opl?tab=inbox) (but each user can only see their own notifications, so that link will only work for you).

---

You can also get these notifications sent to you by email -- to enable that, edit your user profile:

- Edit Profile & Settings ...
- ... Edit Email Settings ...
- ... Inbox: Answers to your questions, comments, chat notifications, and more

So, as well as via your StackExchange "inbox", your notifications can be delivered via email: weekly, daily, or every three hours.

---

Perhaps by "following a topic" you meant 'marking it as a "favorite"'.

I think maybe there's some "notification" when a favorite topic changes, but not the same kind of notification (and maybe no email notification) -- see:

- [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/53585/139866)
- [Feature Request: Providing Notification for favorite questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69886/139866)
- [When Do I get favorite notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171722/139866)
- and more generally [results found containing favorite notification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=favorite+notification)